# SQL Job Step timeout

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, sql-server-agent, sql-server-2012

If a SQL Agent job step executing a stored procedure on a linked server times out,  does the agent kill the SPID on the linked server or does it continue to run on the linked server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a client disconnects from SQL Server, the database engine rolls-back any open transactions prior to the spid terminating.

This applies to all clients, even a "client" Agent Job running via a linked server.

If a stored procedure running via a linked server times out, the connection to the target server will disconnect, causing all open transactions in that session to roll back.

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119865/what-are-all-the-ways-an-open-transaction-will-rollback/119876#119876) shows many of the ways an open transaction can be rolled back.